# How do I identify the file that launched my application

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, clickonce

I'm trying to associate an application with a particular file type and then use that file when the application starts up. It's pretty trivial to [Create File Associations For a ClickOnce Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892924.aspx):

[image: Publish Options > File Associations]

This currently works, so if I have an file with the extension ".tester," my Click Once Deployed application will fire up.

The problem I'm having trouble with is *identifying which file launched the application*.

According to the question [What Event is Triggered When Opening a Custom File?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16476182/1366033), the "file should be available from the command line args", and this [Scott Hanselman Article confirms](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode31SingleInstanceWinFormsAndMicrosoftVisualBasicdll.aspx).

However, when I add the following code, I don't get anything besides the path to the executable when firing the application.

```vb
Dim args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
MsgBox(Join(args, ", "))
```

[image: Command Line Args]

I have confirmed that I'm fetching all the command line arguments.  When I launch the file from the actual command line with some bogus arguments:

```
C:\FileHandler.exe -foo bar
```

The application will display the following:

[image: args 2]

**How do I identify the file that initiated the application?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ClickOnce doesn't pass through standard command line args, but through the [ActivationArguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.hosting.activationarguments.activationdata(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Your file info should be available via 
`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! It's the sort of thing you think they'd at least mention/link to when telling you how to set up the file associations in the first place.