# How to get the path to the file the user uses to launch the Windows application associated with that file type?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, associations, store

I have a WPF application written in C# 11 targeting .NET 7. It will be packaged as MSIX and published to the Microsoft Store. (Although, I am side-loading it for now.) I have added a File Type Association for `.xyz` files to the package manifest.

I sideload the application on my Windows 11 machine successfully. Then, I double-click a `.xyz` file. Windows opens my program, as expected.

However, I cannot retrieve the path to the file that caused the application to open.

I have tried the following:

1. Override `Application.OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)` and use e.Args.

`Args` contains only one argument, and it is of the form: `-ServerName:App.AppXkxw1e314qzr8fyhwy5fza7r57vbx9dph.mca`

2. Call `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`.

This returns two arguments. The first one is the path to the application's DLL (of the form **C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\BLAHBLAHBLAH_1.0.1.0_x64__dijkdkmnhep\MYAPP\MYAPP.dll**), and the second is the same as the only argument in `StartupEventArgs.Args`. (See #1.)

3. Create **Program.cs** and override `Program.Main(string[] args)`.

`args` is empty.

4. Call `Windows.ApplicationModel.AppInstance.GetActivatedEventArgs()`

This returns `null`.

5. Access `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData[0]`.

In .NET 7, `AppDomainSetup` no longer has the `ActivationArguments` property.

#### References

[Handle Protocol Activation and Redirection in Packaged Apps](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2019/05/10/handle-protocol-activation-and-redirection-in-packaged-apps/)

[How do I identify the file that launched my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34599467/how-do-i-identify-the-file-that-launched-my-application)

[Get the path of the file that launched my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59744428/get-the-path-of-the-file-that-launched-my-app)

[Get file that the user opened the application with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45355573/get-file-that-the-user-opened-the-application-with)

[Get path+filename of file that was opened with my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28004975/get-pathfilename-of-file-that-was-opened-with-my-application/28005158#28005158)

Thank you for any assistance or ideas you may have. I have run out of things to try and places to Google/Bing.

Comment: Can you show the details of your "package manafest"? File associations are usually stored in the registry https://superuser.com/questions/266268/where-in-the-registry-does-windows-store-with-which-program-to-open-certain-file with `...\Shell\Open\Command = "[executable]" "%1"`. Perhaps the `%1` is somehow missing?

Comment: Store apps use `DelegateExecute` so there is no "%1" in the Registry entry.

Answer (score 1):

I guess [talking to the duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) helped because I was finally able to solve the issue after writing this up.

Here is how to add a **Declaration** of type *File Type Association* to the `Package.appxmanifest` file in Visual Studio 2022:

- **Display name:** Some text describing the file type
- **Logo:** optional, but if you add one and then delete it, it leaves an empty `<uap:Logo />` element in `Package.appxmanifest` which you **must delete manually**.
- **Info tip:** optional
- **Name:** Extension *without* the leading period (e.g., *txt*)
- **Supported file type**

  - **Content type:** Known MIME type (e.g., *text/html*)
  - **File type:** Extension *with* leading period (e.g., *.txt*)

#### Example

```
        <uap:Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
          <uap:FileTypeAssociation Name="custom">
            <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
              <uap:FileType ContentType="text/xml">.custom</uap:FileType>
            </uap:SupportedFileTypes>
            <uap:DisplayName>My Custom File Type</uap:DisplayName>
            <uap:EditFlags OpenIsSafe="true"/>
          </uap:FileTypeAssociation>
        </uap:Extension>
```

Once that is all sorted, `protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)` returns the path to the file the user opened as the first argument in `e.Args`.

In addition, `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` returns the path as the second argument. (The first argument is the path of the DLL.)

#### Error Messages

This error message refers to the empty `<uap:Logo />` element. Note that the error is in `Package.appxmanifest`, not in the `app.manifest` file, nor is it on line 38. It would be nice if the package errors were specific and accurate.

`Error info: error C00CE169: App manifest validation error: The app manifest must be valid as per schema: Line 38, Column 14, Reason: '' violates minLength constraint of '1'.`

#### References

After pouring through dozens of less helpful ones, these sites helped me resolve the issue.

- [Handle file activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-file-activation)
- [uap:Extension (Windows 10)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-uap-extension)
- [Integrate your desktop app with Windows using packaging extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-extensions)